# Is there a compiler difference between an if-check and inline conditional?

Tags: c++, if-statement, g++, variable-assignment

I've recently begun using flags to handle an input loop's validity condition so it can be checked elsewhere inside the loop rather than having to redo the same check multiple times. However, I'm unsure how best to assign the flag. Is there a generally standard practice regarding this, or just personal style? What, differences are there in the compiled code, if any?

For example, instead of the following code:

```
bool isValidSize;

do {
    std::cout << "Enter the font size (8-12): ";
    std::cin >> fontSize;

    if (fontSize >= MIN_FONT_SIZE && fontSize <= MAX_FONT_SIZE) {
        isValidSize = true;
    } else {
        isValidSize = false;
        std::cout << "Invalid size. ";
    }
} while (!isValidSize);
```

the if-statement can be changed to make it more clear what `isValidSize` is set to at a glance:

```
    isValidSize = (fontSize >= MIN_FONT_SIZE && fontSize <= MAX_FONT_SIZE);
    if (!isValidSize) {
        std::cout << "Invalid size. ";
    }
```

Would this be compiled as an extra if-check? Is there any portability benefit to having the assignment separate from anything else? From just looking at the code, it seems the benefit of the first way is possibly only one branch but an additional assignment per rep and also has an else?

Comment: You can easily check what different compilers generate with different optimization options at https://godbolt.org/ . But, in any case, before trying to optimize you should benchmark/profile the code to see if it even matters - and if not, always write the most clear version.

Comment: This kind of micro-optimization is almost always silly. Write it the way that makes the most sense to a reader.  Let the compiler do its job. Gcc is very good at optimizing cases like this. If you're curious, it's a worthwhile skill to learn how to compile to assembly (easy) and look at what happens for yourself (a bit harder). Then realize no two compilers are alike, including versions of the same compiler. @JesperJuhl is right about godbolt.org. It's very cool.

Comment: There's no point in worrying about nanoseconds in an interactive input loop. Use the one you find most readable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been more clear. I wasn't asking for whether one would be more optimal. I agree that micro-optimization and pre-optimization are the root of all evil. :) I was really just wondering how the compiler behaved as to whether or not there actually was a difference, and what they were. My only questions as to benefit/comparison were as to readability and if there was a standard practice. I'm still a student, so I'm always looking for more ways to have more mature code compared to what they teach us at school. Thanks so much for godbolt! :)

Comment: Use the one you find most readable.  Most importantly not readable by you, but readable by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences: [proof](https://godbolt.org/g/wihPs7).

Tested on `GCC 6.3` with optimisations (`-O3`).

Go for what you think is the more readable one.

Comment: Thanks! Is one of them more standard as far as general practice readability-wise, or does it really just not matter at all?

Comment: @BrainFRZ In that case it really depends. Anyway IMHO I prefer the second snippet. I find it more readable.